# Who was the creative writer for Mass Effect 3: Citadel?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm trying to find out who was the writer for the DLC Citadel for ME3.

Especially the Identity Theft quest series was a firework of references and humour and I'd love to read/see/game more of the writer of it.

Who was the creative writer for Mass Effect 3: Citadel?

Comment: I assume you've tried looking at the credits in game? I've no idea if its there but games these days seem to have huge credits in them so I'd be surprised if they didn't have details in there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The credits list seven writers: Brianne Battye, John Dombrow, Chris Hepler, Cathleen Rootsaert, Mac Walters, Jay Watamaniuk, and Patrick Weekes. They are listed in alphabetical order, not in an order of rank/seniority/contribution.

In all seven cases, these writers have worked on various Bioware games. It seems a little obvious in hindsight, but the best place to find similar writing would be the same studio, i.e. the Dragon Age series.

Source: http://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/mass-effect-3-citadel/credits, but if anyone asks I watched through the end credits myself.